# jQuery load page on end of list

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I have a list of items

```
<ul class="coments-list">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

i would like to load with jquery more items, after ajax success

```
...
success: function (id) {
   $('.comment-list').load('/coments?commentid=' + id);
},
...
```

It is not the problem in any code before this, but this code replaces the whole list with loaded `<li>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [JQuery append function](https://api.jquery.com/append/). For example:

```
$('.coments-list').append('<li>4</li>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKd7E/).

To combine load and append you can do it like this:

```
...
success: function (id) {
    $('.coments-list').append($(document.createElement("li")).load('/coments?commentid=' + id));
},
...
```

It appends the `<li>` element to the coments-list and loads it with data from source passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new div hidden where load your content. After you can and append its content to your ul

try:

```
$(document).append('<div id="content-load" style="display:none;"></div>');
$(document).find('#content-load').load('/coments?commentid=' + id);

$('.comment-list').append($(document).find('#content-load').html());
```

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about this too, but was hoping there is something in jquery to directly do it.

Answer (score 0):

get the content you're trying to render, and then use append instead of load.

Comment: Perhaps you can show the op how it's done? It would certainly be a better answer then...